# ASP.NET scrollbar not moving down on row select which is not visible

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview

I have some 100 rows for example in gridview and gridview is small. When I press the down arrow key and when the selection of row thuis moves down, the scroll bar is not moving down :( How to rectify this?

User needs that the scroll bar should also go down so as to see the row.

Answer (score 0):

Add MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback  in your page directive.

Example:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback ="true"%>
```

Comment: Don, thank you, I tried that earlier, but it doesn't work for GRIDVIEW. Looks like it is only for some other things and not for gridview. I am just struggling to find one for row inside the gridview when I select using key down, the scrollbars not moving